# MS Access: How to query a second table when value is not found in the first

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, subquery

I have a simple query to find values in a related table. In some cases, the value is null.  In this case, I would like to query a second table.  I looked at the NZ function but it won't allow for another query operation.  I assume I am looking at a nested query or an operation like SQL COALASCE.

I want to first search tbl_bi_item_mstr

```
SELECT tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr, tbl_bi_item_mstr.bi_item_nr
FROM tbl_cust_fcst_demd LEFT JOIN tbl_bi_item_mstr ON tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr = tbl_bi_item_mstr.bi_item_nr;
```

For the null values, I would want to find them in tbl_cust_xref

```
SELECT tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr, tbl_cust_xref.bi_item_nr
FROM tbl_cust_fcst_demd INNER JOIN tbl_cust_xref ON tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr = tbl_cust_xref.cust_item_nr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join both tables, and use `Nz()` between the result fields.

```
SELECT d.cust_item_nr, Nz(i.bi_item_nr, x.bi_item_nr) AS bi_item_nr
FROM (tbl_cust_fcst_demd d 
LEFT JOIN tbl_bi_item_mstr i ON d.cust_item_nr = i.bi_item_nr)
INNER JOIN tbl_cust_xref x ON d.cust_item_nr = x.cust_item_nr
```

For >1 JOIN, parentheses are needed.
Using table aliases makes the SQL easier readable.

Comment: Correct with one change. INNER JOIN must be LEFT JOIN to match null values

Comment: I assumed that `tbl_cust_xref` contains all customers. If it doesn't, you are right: then you need two LEFT JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional query might be tricky, you could do it in a macro or vba etc, but that would need to be done outside the sql statement.  If you wish to keep it simple, I'd suggest unioning 2 tables with a differentiating column.

Example code for the union below:

```
SELECT 
tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr
, tbl_bi_item_mstr.bi_item_nr
, 1 as "src_priority"
FROM tbl_cust_fcst_demd LEFT JOIN tbl_bi_item_mstr ON tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr = tbl_bi_item_mstr.bi_item_nr

Union

SELECT tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr
, tbl_cust_xref.bi_item_nr
, 2 as "src_priority"
FROM tbl_cust_fcst_demd INNER JOIN tbl_cust_xref ON tbl_cust_fcst_demd.cust_item_nr 

Order by src_priority
```

You may still work on the consumption requirement, I'd recommend keeping the union as a query/view and create another select for the  consumption query (subject to your requirements and performance), where you can aggregate or partition etc.

Answer (score 0):

Andre's suggestion was helpful. INNER JOIN was required to change to LEFT JOIN or the null values were ignored.

```
SELECT d.cust_item_nr, Nz([i].[bi_item_nr],[x].[bi_item_nr]) AS bi_item_nr
FROM (tbl_cust_fcst_demd AS d 
LEFT JOIN tbl_bi_item_mstr AS i ON d.cust_item_nr = i.bi_item_nr) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_cust_xref AS x ON d.cust_item_nr = x.cust_item_nr
```